Tangent definition with a newton raphson question example
I'm very confused about the definition of a tangent, I was told its a straight line that touches a curve at a point, but if extended does not cross the curve at any other point. 
In this question if u see for part a) using the Newton Raphson method for, values of $x_0$ and larger you find that the $x$ values will become further and further away from the root in the function. However I was confused as to how I can even use values of $x_0 > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ ,since you can't make a tangent line on those points as the line will touch at the point but will then proceed to cut through the graph, meaning it can't be a tangent, but the Newton Raphson method can only be used for tangents.
A similar confusion I had was with the sine graph, if I had the line $y=1$ this would touch all the peaks of the sine graph ,so there will be infinite points where it touches. However this line would still be considered a tangent. So now I have no idea what a tangent is ,if someone could clear this up for me please.ps I'm in secondary school.

Tangent doesn’t mean “crosses the graph at only one point.” It means “touches the graph at only one point very close to the point of tangency.” So if the line of tangency intersects the graph “far away,” that isn’t a problem.

So what are you saying is a tangent is a line that touches the graph at only one point ,and at that point its considered a tanget to the graph .However this line if extented can still be intersect other parts of the graph?

Newton-Raphson roots for successive iterates is given by:
$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f}{f'}$$
In the neighborhood of a root, when tangent intersection on x-axis is successively advancing towards the desired root during convergence
$$\frac{f}{f'}>0$$
This is calculated and plotted.
$$f =\dfrac{1}{5} + x e^{-x^2}, ~~f' = e^{-x^2} \left(1-2 x^2\right)$$

For $ x>\dfrac{1}{\sqrt {2}},~ \dfrac{f}{f'} $ is a negative quantity so does not converge beyond vertical asymptote   $ x>\dfrac{1}{\sqrt {2}}.$

for values of x<2^(-1/2) however it would converge to the root , but if i were to draw tangents on some of those x values in order to get the next iterative x value to draw another tangent the tangent line would not only just touch the curve at the point of tangency but also intersect the cover at another part  of the curve , would this line still be considered a tangent even though it has intersected the curve at another point?

To proceed with iteration the first tangent should cut the x-axis. If not, the method fails, and so it is the challenge from there on.
